# How to wait for a certain value in API json response

Tags: api, cypress

I am working on Cypress API, trying to get a certain response but the problem is that I need to wait until I get a particular response, different from the previous one.

For example, repeating until `"activated: true"` and `"fileType not inprogress"`.

This is the initial repsonse,

```js
[
    {
        "filenameSource": "test",
        "fileExt": "mp4",
        "uniqueId": "18564Cm_BTo7Q0Sb0xCT",
        "fileName": "test.mp4",
        "title": "Test Video",
        "language": "##",
        "validFrom": "2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "rating": 0,
        "aspect": "null",
        "duration": -1,
        "fps": 0,
        "activated": false,
        "fileSize": 0,
        "importTime": "2022-11-07T12:14:31.813Z",
        "fileType": "inprogress"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of code you've tried, and attempt to explain the issue more clearly? It is a bit confusing trying to parse what issue you're running into and what your correct workflow should be.

Comment: Basically, I am getting this JSON response and I want to wait until this response updates to "activated: true" and usually it takes around 30-60 seconds. The problem is that I cannot make the next API call until I get the response (with true) from this. Hope it is now clear.

Comment: So you get a response from the API, and then need to wait for a new API response? Does your app make additional requests to fetch the new response?

Comment: To make it simple for you to understand, here are the details:
- In the 1st request, I am adding a new product (POST) and just fetching its ID.
- In the 2nd request, I am deleting it but the problem is that the product will only be deleted when my product is activated (activated: true from GET product detail request) and that will take around 60 secs. Hope I am able to explain it now?

Answer (score 3):

I think [Request Polling](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Request-Polling) is what you are trying to do

```js
function req(attempts = 0) {

  if (attempts === 100) {
    throw new Error('Too many attempts')
  }

  cy.request('GET', ...)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => {

      const data = resp.body
      
      if (data[0].activated) {
        return                             // break out of the recursive loop
      }
      
      cy.wait(200)
      req(++attempts)                      // else recurse
    })
}

cy.request('POST', ...)          // initiate product

req()                            // wait for activated 

cy.request('DELETE', ...)        // now delete product
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve it with Cypress recurse function. Here is the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-recurse.

Thanks!

Comment: an example here would have been helpful.